# Winform ComboBox- Default Value Cannot Be Set

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, default-value

I have a simple `comboBox` control on my `Winform`.
I would like to set one of the items of comboBox, as the default item that will be shown on form load:

```
duration_ComboBox.SelectedItem = duration_ComboBox.Items.IndexOf("0 minutes");
        duration_ComboBox.Text = duration_ComboBox.SelectedText;
```

I do have the **0 minutes** item in the comboBox, but on from load the field remains empty.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `Combo.SelectedItem`, set  `Combo.SelectedIndex`.

duration_ComboBox.SelectedIndex = duration_ComboBox.Items.IndexOf("0 minutes");

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not the first index. I would like to set it per textual item.

Comment: Then try and use Combo.SelectedIndex = Combo.Items.IndexOf("Text");

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOFAcrobatics
{
    public partial class ComboBoxTesting : Form
    {
        public ComboBoxTesting()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboBoxTesting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> items = new List<String>()
            {
                "0 minutes",
                "1 minutes",
                "2 minutes"
            };

            foreach (String item in items)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }

            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```